# How to create MouseClick event to detect which node is clicked? - javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I want to do global `MouseClick event` to detect which node is clicked in `JavaFX`. I mean when someone will click a button then `event.getSource` will return me reference to this button.

Any ideas, how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go about this would be to have a static variable somewhere that was of type Node, and then in the listener of the button, just assign a reference to the button in the handler to that button. ex:

```
public Class test {
  public static Node whichClick;

  myButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e){
      whichClick = myButton;                        
    }
  });
}
```

And then you could access that variable from wherever.